# Is this CORS exploitable?

Tags: html, file-upload, cors

So i was able to upload a html file on a server i'm allowed to test. The file is uploaded on a subdomain of the main server. Knowing that they allow CORS for anything.domain.com, is it possible to exploit this CORS by uploading a POC html page and send the CORS data to my external server?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Use pseudonyms (like "example.com" and "foo.example.com") but please be clear about what the relationships between the domain you're uploading to, the domain the page is served from, and the domain you're making the CORS request from. Additionally, you need to specify what the CORS policy actually is (what Access-Control-* headers are returned) for the relevant domain(s), and what kind of security the target site uses (for example, if it is simply a public site allowing everybody access to everything, then CORS isn't a vuln because there isn't anything to secure).

Comment: @CBHacking 
While testing example.com i was able to upload a html file on subdomain.example.com - The Access-Control header is set for anything.example.com and when i insert subdomain.example.com the returned header is subdomain.example.com with Access-Control-Allow-Credentials set to true. My question is, it's possible to extract data with cors by uploading cors html poc on subdomain.example.com and send that data to my external server?

Comment: When you say "anything.example.com" do you mean "example.com and all of its subdomains", "all subdomains of example.com", or the literal string "*.example.com"? Are you sending CORS requests to "example.com" or to "subdomain.example.com", and are you sending them from "subdomain.example.com" or from an external site?

Comment: @CBHacking,
I mean "example.com and all of its subdomains". I'm sending the cors request to "example.com" from "subdomain.example.com" and it seems to be working. However what i'm asking here is, how can i receive the data on my external server (if possible).

Comment: you can send a packet but you can't receive the response from CORS, so in your case you try to upload something, you do not hit the CORS

Answer (score 2):

This site is vulnerable, if the following assumptions are correct:

- example.com has **something to attack** (data you want to retrieve that only other users can see, or actions you want to take that only other users can take).
- example.com uses cookies (with or without the samesite flag) or HTTP authentication (basic or digest) for session management, instead of using something like tokens stored in local/session storage.
- CORS requests *from* subdomain.example.com sent *to* example.com receive a response with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: subdomain.example.com` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.
- The requests you want to make (in somebody else's session) to example.com are simple requests (they use content types that could be sent from HTML forms and no custom headers) or else example.com allows subdomain.example.com to specify those content types and/or headers in CORS requests.

Assuming all of the above points are true, you could write a page that makes malicious CORS requests to example.com (stealing other users' data, or stealing CSRF tokens and using them to launch CSRF attacks to take actions as other users) and (if relevant) passes the responses somewhere you can retrieve them, upload that page so it's served from subdomain.example.com, and trick victims into visiting your malicious page while signed into example.com.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wasn't sure if this was possible as usually CORS issues are verified by placing the poc page directly into your external domain. While here the poc page is uploaded on subdomain.example.com

Comment: For most purposes - with some exceptions around cookies - subdomains are treated the same as external domains. If you can host your own content on a subdomain (and don't require control over the server behavior), that is strictly better than doing it on an external domain; anything (client-side) you could do if the subdomain were instead an external domain will still work, but in addition, you can receive and set cookies for the root domain.

Comment: Can you clarify this: example.com uses cookies (without the samesite flag)... for session management, instead of using something like tokens stored in local/session storage.

We use a centralized authentication site with interactive login, so user gets redirected to identity server, logs in, and then gets redirected to the main site. The main site then pulls the auth tokens from the cookie and stores it in local storage which the site then uses for API calls. Are these API's vulnerable if they had ACAO: *?

Comment: ACAO: * is almost never vulnerable (only if the server is authorizing clients by IP or something, rather than by any user authentication). ACAO: * does not allow reading the responses of authenticated requests. If you specify `withCredentials = true`, and the server responds with ACAO: * instead of with the actual origin, the browser will act as though the server didn't serve any ACAO: header at all (SOP will be fully enforced).